# ActiveXObject Support in jQuery? How is it Possible

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is for  Non-IE browsers-

I was working on a requirement which needed a XML file to be parsed. After looking at some  options, i ended up finding $.parseXML in  jQuery.
It worked fine and i can now read the content of the XML from there. But what surprised me was this-

Definition of $.parseXML is-
$.parseXML = `function (n){
    var r,i;if(!n||"string"!=typeof n)return null;
    try{
        e.DOMParser
        ? (i=new DOMParser,r=i.parseFromString(n,"text/xml"))
        : (r=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM"),r.async="false",r.loadXML(n))
    }catch(o){
      r=t
    }
    return r&&r.documentElement&&!r.getElementsByTagName("parsererror").length||b.error("Invalid XML: "+n),r}`

Now, if you look at the code, the part '**r=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")**' is what confuses me the most.
Normally, if we try the same thing independently, then the following  error is  thrown-

```
ReferenceError: ActiveXObject is not defined
```

Can someone explain me how  is this made possible in jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code inside the function definition is meant for IE only.
The ActiveX code is present as a fallback mechanism in case the browser is IE and doesn't support DOMParser(IE9 Supports DOMParser). My guess it that it's still there in case of executing the jquery code in IE8 and below.